# Simple JavaScript function to blur an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, pixastic

I'm using a [jQuery plugin][1] to create a blur an image with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    Pixastic.process(img, "blurfast", {amount:1});
}
document.body.appendChild(img);
img.src = "image.jpg";

});
```

How can I rewrite this so than rather than creating the image I can just assign it to `< img class="blurthisimage" >`?

UPDATE:

New code still not working:

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="blurthisimage" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var img = $(".blurthisimage");
img.onload = function() {
    Pixastic.process(img, "blurfast", {amount:1});
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`img = new Image();`

to

`img = $(".blurthisimage");`

**UPDATE**
Try checking to see if the image is loaded with this

```
if (img[0].complete == true) {
    Pixastic.process(img[0], "blurfast", {amount:1});
}
else {
    img.load(function () {
        Pixastic.process(img[0], "blurfast", {amount:1});
    });
}
```

if you wanted to have this work on multiple images use the following:

```
img.each(function(index, element)
{
    if (img[index].complete == true) {
        Pixastic.process(img[index], "blurfast", {amount:1});
    }
    else {
        img.load(function () {
            Pixastic.process(img[index], "blurfast", {amount:1});
        });
    }
});
```

If that doesn't work add an alert to inside your `onload` function to see if it even fires

Comment: thank you but it's not working. I've updated my post with the new code

Comment: still not working unfortunately. ive put an alert on img.load and it's not triggering it at all

Comment: @fxfuture what about in the if statement. the Image may be cached therefore it's not going to the `img.load` function

Comment: sorry it's the other way around. the img.load function is triggering the alert but not blurring the image

Comment: and the if statement is not triggering anything

Comment: @fxfuture Change `Pixastic.process(img` to `Pixastic.process(img[0]` The first is a jQuery object containing the img and the second is the image itself.

Comment: when i put this into my wordpress site it doesn't work at all. any ideas why this could be?

Comment: With wordpress you'll need to change every `$` to `jQuery`

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't make any difference. I've used exactly the same code so confused why it's not working

Comment: On wordpress it's not triggering the onload function, just the if statement. also the code seems to conflict with jquery supersized but even if I remove reference to supersized this it still doesn't work

Comment: fixed it :) it was a conflict with the script

Answer (score 1):

Is the `img.onload` function getting hit? If the code is not even getting into the function it might be because you instantiate the `.onload` code in jQuery's `.ready()` function which waits until the page is loaded to run the code (see the [`ready()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)) . By the time the function gets instantiated the image has already been loaded so that event will never fire.